# $f:R\rightarrow R$ is twice differentiable with $f''(x)>0$. Prove f cannot have 3 zeroes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$f:R\rightarrow R$ is twice differentiable with $f''(x)>0$. Prove f cannot have 3 zeroes.

I want to use Rolle's to prove there's at most one zero, but Rolle's requires there be an interval where f(a)=f(b) and a!=b and no interval is given. The other thing I can notice is because $f''(x)>0$ that qualitatively it's concaving up the entire function so that tells me there can only be at most one zero because in order for there to be multiple zeroes it needs to decrease. I don't think that's much of a proof though.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2-1$ has more than one zero. Assume $f$ has three zeros, and use Rolle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ has three or more zeroes. Let $a,b,c$ zeroes of $f$ with $a<b<c.$

Then, by Rolle, there are $u,v$ with $a<u<b <v <c$ such that $f'(u)=f'(v)=0$. Again by Rolle: there is $w$ such that $u<w<v$ and $f''(w)=0.$ A contradiction !

Answer (score 1):

The condition $f''(x)>0$ tells us that the first derivative is a strictly increasing function.

If $a$ and $b$ are zeros of $f$, then Rolle's theorem provides us $c$ with $a<c<b$ and $f'(c)=0$. In particular, $f'(x)>0$ for $x>c$ and $f'(x)<0$ for $x<c$.

Therefore the function can vanish only once over $(-\infty,c)$ and only once over $(c,\infty)$. Finally, note that $f(c)<0$, because $c>a$ and $f$ is strictly decreasing over $(a,c)$.